# How do you get values from dynamic controls in a ListView on postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've recently had to go back to dealing with webforms code and have run into an issue trying to update an existing page that shows a list of survey responses.

I have a ListView showing details of people who have answered a survey.
When you click on an icon in the row that row enters edit mode and shows their information (name, email etc) as input boxes.

So far so good, now I need to add the questions and the answers for that survey and that person. Writing them out is easy, but when the postback happens the row goes back to the ItemTemplate and the controls are gone.

I know with dynamic controls you are supposed to create the in Page_Init so webforms can rebind them, but here the controls aren't created until the ListItem ItemEditing event, and the data saved in the ItemUpdating event.

I'm stuck on how I could make the controls in the right place with the right data at the right point in the lifecycle. Right now I'm trying to pull the values from Request.Form but with a CheckboxList it's hard to figure out what has been selected.

Edit: New example that should actually run

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="QuestionExample.aspx.cs" Inherits="QuestionExample" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <table>
        <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="LV" OnItemEditing="LV_OnItemEditing" OnItemUpdating="LV_OnItemUpdating">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder></td>
                    </tr>       
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"/>
                ID: <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLeadID" Text="<%# ((Lead)Container.DataItem).LeadID %>" /> Name: <%# ((Lead)Container.DataItem).Name %><br/>                
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                ID: <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLeadID" Text="<%# ((Lead)Container.DataItem).LeadID %>" /> <asp:Label runat="server">Name</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="tbName" Text="<%# ((Lead)Container.DataItem).Name %>"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Panel runat="server" id="pnlQuestions"></asp:Panel>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
         </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class QuestionExample : Page
{
    #region fake data

    protected List<Question> Questions = new List<Question>()
    {
        new Question { QuestionID = 0, QuestionType = QuestionType.Textbox, QuestionText = "TextBox", Options = null },
        new Question { QuestionID = 1, QuestionType = QuestionType.DropDownList, QuestionText = "DDL", Options = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C"} },
    };

    protected List<Lead> Leads = new List<Lead>
    {
        new Lead { LeadID = 0, Name = "Bob", Answers = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "TextBox", "Hi" }, { "DDL", "B" } } },
        new Lead { LeadID = 1, Name = "Fred", Answers = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "TextBox", "Stuff" }, { "DDL", "C" } } },
    };

    #endregion    

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LV.DataSource = Leads;
        LV.DataBind();
    }

    protected void LV_OnItemEditing(object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        LV.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        LV.DataBind();
        var leadLabel = (Label)LV.Items[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("lblLeadID");
        var leadID = int.Parse(leadLabel.Text);
        var panel = (Panel)LV.Items[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("pnlQuestions");
        var lead = Leads.First(l => l.LeadID == leadID);
        foreach (var answer in lead.Answers)
        {
            var question = Questions.First(q => q.QuestionText == answer.Key);
            panel.Controls.Add(CreatQuestionControl(question, lead, true));
        }
    }

    protected Control CreatQuestionControl(Question question, Lead lead, bool setAnswers)
    {
        Control result = null;
        switch (question.QuestionType)
        {
            case QuestionType.Textbox:
                var tb = new TextBox();
                if (setAnswers)
                {
                    var answer = lead.Answers[question.QuestionText];
                    tb.Text = answer;
                }
                result = tb;
                break;
            case QuestionType.DropDownList:
                var ddl = new DropDownList { DataSource = question.Options };
                ddl.DataBind();
                if (setAnswers)
                {
                    var answer = lead.Answers[question.QuestionText];
                    ddl.SelectedValue = answer;
                }
                result = ddl;
                break;
        }

        return result;
    }

    protected void LV_OnItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get input data here somehow

        LV.EditIndex = -1;
    }
}

public class Lead
{
    public int LeadID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; }
    public List<string> Options { get; set; }
}

public enum QuestionType
{
    Textbox = 0,
    DropDownList = 1,
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without seeing your code it's difficult to give a complete answer, but basically you need to recreate the control tree, including the dynamically created controls, on postback.

You can do this, for example, in the Page_Load event handler.

You can store any data you need to recreate the control tree in ViewState so that it is available on PostBack.

I'm not sure what you mean by:

> ... when the postback happens the row goes back to the ItemTemplate

I would expect EditIndex to stay unchanged after a postback, unless you explicitly modify it, and therefore the edit row to be unchanged, and EditItemTemplate to be used.

If you can post a simplified sample that illustrates your problem I (or someone else) may be able to help further.

**UPDATE**

Based on the posted code, you need to recreate the dynamic controls in the ItemUpdating event handler and add them to the control tree in the same order as you created them in the ItemEditing event handler.  I.e. you probably need to repeat the code:

```
var questionPannel = lL.Items[e.ItemIndex].FindControl("lead_table") as HtmlTable;
var campaignQuestionsTableRow = questionPannel.FindControl("campaign_questions") as HtmlTableRow;

var questions = GetQuestions();

foreach(var question in questions)
{
    // This builds a WebControl for the dynamic question
    var control = CreateQuestionControl(question);
    campaignQuestionsTableRow.AddControl(control); 
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

When updating, you need to recreate the dynamic controls on PostBack.  Change your Page_Load event handler to something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LV.DataSource = Leads;
    LV.DataBind();
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        if (LV.EditIndex >= 0)
        {
            var leadLabel = (Label)LV.Items[LV.EditIndex].FindControl("lblLeadID");
            var leadID = int.Parse(leadLabel.Text);
            var panel = (Panel)LV.Items[LV.EditIndex].FindControl("pnlQuestions");
            var lead = Leads.First(l => l.LeadID == leadID);
            foreach (var answer in lead.Answers)
            {
                var question = Questions.First(q => q.QuestionText == answer.Key);
                panel.Controls.Add(CreatQuestionControl(question, lead, true));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

On the first Postback (click on Edit), EditIndex will be -1, and the dynamic controls are created in the OnItemEditing handler.

On the second Postback (click on Update), EditIndex will be the index of the line you're editing, and you need to recreate the dynamic controls in Page_Load.  If you do this, you'll find your posted values when you get to the OnItemUpdating event handler.

While I think it's worthwhile understanding how to use dynamic controls in this way, in a production app I'd probably use a Repeater inside the EditItemTemplate as suggested by Elisheva Wasserman.  The Repeater could contain a UserControl that encapsulates the logic to hide/show UI elements based on the question type.

Comment: OK., I have added an example. what I mean by goes back to ItemTemplate should hopefully be a bit clearer, questions are only shown in the EditItemTemplate you fill them in, his save and then the page shows the ItemTemplate without those controls.

Comment: I've tried this, but they don't have the values posted back in them. From what I have been able to find I need to create them in Page_Load for the data to rebind, and making them in the iL_ItemUpdating is too late in the lifecycle.

Comment: @Mant101 - Page_Load would be a better place to create them.  Possibly you could check for `IsPostBack && (EditIndex >= 0)` in Page_Load, and recreate the controls there.  If you can provide a minimal complete sample that demonstrates the problem (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I or someone else will be able to help.

Comment: OK, new example that works and shows the problem. I tried putting that check in Page_Load but EditIndex is -1 until you hit the item editing event handler later in the lifecycle.

Comment: @Mant101 - see UPDATE 2 above.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an inside Repeater or listView, which will be bind on item_edit event, instead of recreating dynamics controls every post.
this way:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lL" runat="server" OnItemEditing="lL_ItemEditing"       OnItemUpdating="lL_ItemUpdating">
<itemtemplate>
Read only view here...
</itemtemplate>
 <edititemtemplate>
 <asp:LinkButton D="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />
<table runat="server" ID="lead_table" class="lead_table">
    <tr id="Tr1" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;" runat="server" >
        <td>Name: <asp:TextBox ID="Name" /></td>
        Other Fixed controls...
    </tr>
    <tr runat="server" ID ="campaign_questions">
       <asp:Repeater id='repetur1' runat="server">
         <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label id='lblCaption' runat='server" Text='<%Eval("QuestionTitle")%>' />

<asp:TextBox id='name' runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
    </tr>
</table>
```

on code behind

```
protected void lL_ItemEditing(object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)
{             
var questionPannel = lL.Items[e.ItemIndex].FindControl("lead_table") as HtmlTable;
var campaignQuestionsTableRow = questionPannel.FindControl("campaign_questions") as HtmlTableRow;

// bind fixed controls
var lead = GetLead();
var nameControl = ((TextBox)lL.Items[e.ItemIndex].FindControl("Name"))
nameControl.Text = lead.Name;

// bind dynamic controls
var questions = GetQuestions();

     var rep= (Repeater)lL.Items[e.ItemIndex].FindControl("repeatur1");
rep.DataSource=questions;
 rep.DataBind();
}

protected void lL_ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    // Get fixed fields
   // var lead = GetLead();
    lead.Name = ((TextBox)lL.Items[e.ItemIndex].FindControl("Name")).Text.Trim();
 Repeater rep=(Repeater)e.FindControl("repeatur1"));
   foreach (RepeaterItem item in rep.Items)
{

TextBox t=item.FindControl("txtName") as TextBox;
//do your work here
   }
// Switch out of edit mode
lL.EditIndex = -1;
}
```

Comment: The questions can be completely different controls, one survey may have a radio button list, one textboxes and so on. So I guess the repeater would need every question type in there, and then hide the ones not being used for that question?

Comment: Yes, although it looks complicated, it is a better option, dynamic created controls are not stored in viewstate and couse lot's of bugs. you can use Eval in markup to change visibilty of not needed controls . Use server property Visible and not client propery, so asp.net won't create hiddne controls at all.